# how can I run for loop 4 times

Tags: for-loop

I have an array that I have counted and it equals 4. That is what it should equal. Now I want the foreach loop inside the for loop to only run 4 times. As it stands, I am getting to many results. Below is my latest attempt that does not work.

```
    $networks = array();
    $networks = ! empty( $instance['networks']) ? $instance['networks'] : '';
    $size = count($networks); //size equals 4

    for($i = 0; $i <= $size; $i++){
        foreach ( $this->networks as $key => $value ) {
            $network_names[ $key ] = $value['class'];
        }
     $i++;
    }
```

the networks array is populated from a WordPress widget that has a repeating field section. The section allows the user to set social media icons. I currently have 4 social media icons set. On the front end, the page shows every social media icon available even though there are only 4 set. So I am trying to get the nested foreach loop to only run 4 times.

Comment: Have you tried setting the bound of the loop to 4?  Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: Do you want to do 4 or do you want to do all of the networks. At the moment you're doing 4*network item count because you have a loop in a loop. Is there a problem with just doing the for each?

Comment: You can also do it with a while loop. Seems more sensible in this case.

Comment: Oh I see. You need to filter the networks to only the ones you have set, not loop through them. At the moment what you're doing is saying "go through that list of items 4 times"

Answer (score 1):

Currently your loop is executing 5 times..and you want it to run only 4 times... So Change this condition...`for($i = 0; $i <= $size; $i++)` to either `for($i = 0; $i <$size; $i++)` or `for($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++)` like i.e.

```
$networks = array();
$networks = ! empty( $instance['networks']) ? $instance['networks'] : '';
$size = count($networks); //size equals 4

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    foreach ( $this->networks as $key => $value ) {
        $network_names[ $key ] = $value['class'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but why run it 4 times? Why run it more than once? It makes no sense. OP is doing the exact same work 4 times and the for loop doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I have something more interesting for you..
it's a widget parent with children!
You can change field to load new fields from other classes
here's the link:

https://github.com/hishamdalal/parent_widget